# What is the default folder for cmake to search for libraries in Linux?

Tags: cmake

If I give some libraries in `target_link_libraries` (like GL, Glfw, glew), what is the default place, where cmake search for these libs?

For example:

```
target_link_libraries(aplication GL glfw GLEW)
```

Does Cmake search for these libs in the Path environment variable in Linux? Where can I find these libs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cmake target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html?highlight=target_link_libraries):

> A plain library name: The generated link line will ask the linker to search for the library (e.g. foo becomes -lfoo or foo.lib).

Just to point you in the right direction as to what are the standard linker search paths, [this post on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367600/what-is-the-order-that-linuxs-dynamic-linker-searches-paths-in) explains it.

Comment: Thanks! And as far as I know, with link_libraries command I can add more directories to the cmake to search for during linking...

Comment: There is [target_link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/target_link_directories.html) and [link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/link_directories.html?highlight=link_directories). `link_libraries` links with the libraries.